# Why won't this regexp work in google spreadsheets?

Tags: regex, spreadsheet, expression

I'm trying to extract from a url using a regexp in google spreadsheets.  However the spreadsheet returns **`#VALUE!`** with the following error:  **Invalid regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?<**

Here is the regexp I'm using: `(?<=raid_boss=)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`

A sample url will contain a variable in it that says `raid_boss=name`.  This regexp should extract name.  It works in my testing program, but not in google spreadsheet.

Here is the exact contents of the cell in google spreadsheets: `=REGEXEXTRACT( B1 ; "/(?<=raid_boss=)[-a-zA-{}-9_]+" )`

Any insight or help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The lookbehind feature is unavailable in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like whatever regular-expression engine Google Docs is using doesn't support lookbehind assertions.  They are a relatively rare feature.

But if you use captures, REGEXEXTRACT will return the captured text, so you can do it that way:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT( B1 ; "raid_boss=([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)" )
```

Comment: Thanks, works!  A friend also just showed me this alternate version =regexextract(B1, ".*raid_boss=(.*)&")   Which works fine in google, but has weird (undesired) results in my editor.  Oh well, what works works.

Comment: You don't need the `.*`; regexextract regexes aren't anchored.  Your friend's will get undesirable results if there's another & after the one that ends the raid_boss query parameter - it will grab the longest string it can that ends in a &, and your raid boss will wind up with a long, ampersand-containing name.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not the issue - Google Sheets uses [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt) which lacks lookbehind
along with other useful things.

You could use:

```
regexextract(B1, ".*raid_boss=(.*)")
```

or else native sheet functions like FIND, SUBSTITUTE if that isn't working

Finding a good regex testing tool is tricky - for example you can make something that works in http://rubular.com/ but fails in GSheets.  You need to make sure your tool supports the RE2 flavour eg: https://regoio.herokuapp.com/